# sharepoint lists.asmx updatelistitems removes onclick events from tags

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I'm using soap to update list items (essentially html articles) in a sharepoint list which is all working ok. Its done this way as its updating information from another server.
This is being done through asp.net (in VB) using a Web Reference (referred to as sharepointref below)to the lists.asmx service

However any onclick event added to A tags or any tag is stripped out when using updatelistitems via lists.asmx.
I'm basically wanting to add a bit of JQUERY into the onclick event on some links within the list items.

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#anchor').offset().top},'slow');return false;
```

This just smoothly scrolls to anchor points in the article rather than reloading the article again.

I am assuming that this is a security feature in sharepoint but is there a way round this?

A basic example is:

```
Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
Dim myUpdates as XmlNode= xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Batch","")
myxml = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>"
myxml = myxml & "<Field Name='ID'>1</Field>"
myxml = myxml & "<Field Name='Content_Field'><![CDATA[<a name='anchor'></a><br><br><a href="&chr(34)&"#"&chr(34)&" onclick="&chr(34)&"$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#anchor').offset().top},'slow');return false;"&chr(34)&">test</a>]]></Field>"
 myxml = myxml & "</Method>"
myUpdates.InnerXml =  myxml
Dim mysp As new sharepointref.Lists()
Dim ndLists As XmlNode = mysp.UpdateListItems("Articles",myUpdates)
```

The above all goes in ok except when you look at it in Sharepoint its lost the onclick event.